Count redis queue length in docker
I have a Celery+Redis python application.
I have to find number of tasks in queue. I trying this command, but the output is zero.
I am confident that queue is not empty.
redis-cli -n 1 -h localhost -p 6379 llen celery

(integer) 0

I think I am using invalid arguments.
My redis + celery configuration:
celery:
    build: ./project
    command: celery -A core_app worker  --loglevel=info --concurrency=15 --max-memory-per-child=1000000
    volumes:
      - ./project:/usr/src/app
      - ./project/media:/project/media
      - ./project/logs:/project/logs
    env_file:
      - .env
    environment:
    # environment variables declared in the environment section override env_file
      - DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
      - CELERY_BROKER=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - django
      - redis

  redis:
    build:
      context: ./redis_customization
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: redis:7.2-alpine
    restart: always
    ports:
        - 6379:6379
    # Run the init script
    command: sh -c "./init.sh"
    # Run as privileged to allow the container to change the vm.overcommit_memory setting
    privileged: true


If you think that you are using invalid arguments, why are you not using valid arguments instead? Or: why do you think that you are using invalid arguments, and not that something else is causing the problem?

For example: I read documentation -n means  -- Database number, but I don't understand this description (I was trying different values for this parameter, for all f them result is 0)

Your config file shows that the Celery broker and backend are both using database 0, which is the default. That what the /0 at the end of these Redis URLs means:
- CELERY_BROKER=redis://redis:6379/0
- CELERY_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0

The port and hostname default to 6379 and localhost as well.
So, you should be able to just do:
redis-cli llen celery

This is assuming that you are not using any customized prefixes and are using the default queue. I don't see any of the former in your yaml file but if you are using a custom queue, it'll be something like
redis-cli llen celery.my-custom-queue

Hope this helps!

Nice answer - wish more folks took the time to explain and inform like this.

You used the -n 1 parameter, which indicates using database number 1. Redis has 16 databases by default, numbered from 0 to 15. If you want to use the first database, it might be -n 0 instead of -n 1. Please check if your data is stored in database number 1.

How can I check where is my data?

Presumably by trying redis-cli -n 0 llen celery and successively replacing the zero with 1-15. Or redis-cli -n 0 'KEYS *' if you are unsure of their names.
